# Disallow invoice option when organisation in billing post array is not set to 1

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, payment, rules

I have a custom value 'organisation_type' that will be 1,2 or 3. If this is 1 I want to modify the existing code in the PurchaseOrder.php below to set canUseCheckout to true.

so for instance in the billing Post array on the checkout - if billing['organisation_type'] == 1, then canUseCheckout should be set to true otherwise set to false;

Can anyone suggest how this is done looking at my existing code? 
Is it possible using getQuote() to get all the values from the billing post array?

DisallowInvoice config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
   <modules>
    <AA_DisallowInvoice>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </AA_DisallowInvoice>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <disallowinvoice>
            <class>AA_DisallowInvoice_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>disallowinvoice_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </disallowinvoice>
        <payment>
            <rewrite>
                <method_purchaseorder>AA_DisallowInvoice_Model_Payment_Method_Purchaseorder</method_purchaseorder>
            </rewrite>
        </payment>
    </models>
</global>
```

```
class AA_DisallowInvoice_Model_Payment_Method_Purchaseorder extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Purchaseorder {

public function canUseCheckout()
{
    $this->_shippingAddressCheck();
    return $this->_canUseCheckout;
}

/**
 * If the shipping address is different to the billing address, prevent use within checkout
 */
protected function _shippingAddressCheck()
{
    if (! Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getSameAsBilling()) {
        $this->_canUseCheckout = false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zabs,used the `isAvailable` function ,which is better solution:

```
public function isAvailable($quote = null)
    {
        return parent::isAvailable($quote) && !empty($quote)
            && in_array(1,$quote->getBillingAddress()->getData('organisation_type'));
    }
```

if this logic is not working .try below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567979/set-payment-method-cash-on-delivery-on-particular-state-only/24568989

Just change code of `filterpaymentmethod` function

```
 <?php
class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Observer {
 public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
            /* call get payment method */
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();

        if($method->getCode()=='purchaseorder'){
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            $BillAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
            if($BillAddress->getData('organisation_type')==1){
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
            $result->isAvailable = true;
            return;
            }
            else{
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
            $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I haven't quite used this solution for my own particular app but this is the clearly best way to do it so will accept this answer from @amit-bera

Comment: All the thanks goes to you (and clever gurus like yourself who help us all out on this site) :)